# When Livewire updates the Component it disappears

Tags: laravel, alpine.js

I have a Cart Sidebar that slides in when clicked and slides out when closed with AlpineJS. So far so good it works fine. The problem occurs when Livewire updates this Component. The Component disappears and it wont show up again unless I refresh the site.

cart-component.blade.php

```
<div :class="cartOpen ? 'translate-x-0 ease-out' : 'translate-x-full ease-in'" class="fixed right-0 top-0 max-w-xs w-full h-full px-6 py-4 transition duration-300 transform overflow-y-auto bg-white border-l-2 border-gray-300 hidden dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-white" x-init="() => { $el.classList.remove('hidden'); }">
    <div class="flex items-center justify-between">
        <h3 class="text-2xl font-medium text-gray-700 dark:text-white">Your cart ({{Cart::count()}} items)</h3>
        <button @click="cartOpen = !cartOpen" class="text-gray-600 dark:text-white focus:outline-none">
            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg>
        </button>
    </div>
    <hr class="my-3">
    @foreach (Cart::content() as $item)
        <div class="flex justify-between mt-6">
            <div class="flex">
                <img class="h-20 w-20 object-cover rounded" src=" {{ $item->model->image }} " alt="{{ $item->name }}">
                <div class="mx-3">
                    <h3 class="text-sm text-gray-600 dark:text-white">{{ $item->name }}</h3>
                    <div class="flex items-center mt-2">
                        <button wire:click.prevent="increaseQty('{{$item->rowId}}')" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M12 9v3m0 0v3m0-3h3m-3 0H9m12 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
                        </button>
                        <span class="text-gray-700 dark:text-white mx-2">{{ $item->qty }}</span>
                        <button wire:click.prevent="decreaseQty('{{$item->rowId}}')" class="text-gray-500 dark:text-white focus:outline-none focus:text-gray-600">
                            <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M15 12H9m12 0a9 9 0 11-18 0 9 9 0 0118 0z"></path></svg>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <span class="text-gray-600 dark:text-white">{{ number_format((float) $item->price * $item->qty , 2)}}€</span>
            <button wire:click.prevent="removeItem('{{ $item->rowId }}')" class="text-gray-600 dark:text-white focus:outline-none">
                <svg class="h-5 w-5" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"></path></svg>
            </button>
        </div>
    @endforeach

    <a href="{{ route('checkout') }}" class="flex items-center justify-center mt-4 px-3 py-2 bg-blue-600 text-white text-sm uppercase font-medium rounded hover:bg-blue-500 focus:outline-none focus:bg-blue-500">
        <span>Checkout</span>
        <svg class="h-5 w-5 mx-2" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor"><path d="M17 8l4 4m0 0l-4 4m4-4H3"></path></svg>
    </a>
</div>
```

CartComponent.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Cart;

class CartComponent extends Component
{

    public function increaseQty($id)
    {
        Cart::update($id, Cart::get($id)->qty +1);
    }

    public function decreaseQty($id)
    {
        Cart::update($id, Cart::get($id)->qty -1);
    }

    public function removeItem($id)
    {
        Cart::remove($id);
    }


    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.cart-component');
    }
}
```

Clicking the cartOpen button still applies the class but it just won't show up

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes there may be a problem that AlpineJS doesn't detect changes made by livewire... In my case adding

```js
<script>
    Livewire.hook('element.initialized',() => {
        window.Alpine.discoverUninitializedComponents((el) => {
            window.Alpine.initializeComponent(el);
        })
    });
</script>
```

worked perfectly. What the code does is it is listening for `element.initialized` (event emited by livewire when it adds code in a request) and manually initializes alpine components!

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it and it didnt help, i also tested a lot of other methods and cant find one that is working. I guess I will just ditch the sidebar idea.

Answer (score 0):

not the best Solution but i removed the
`x-init="() => { $el.classList.remove('hidden'); }"`.
atleast it works now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the comment on the top of the component, if there is any.
Any html including comments must be inside the one root tag.

Answer (score 0):

Note sometimes you need to add a `div` with `wire:ignore`. This will help maintain the html element structure.

> you can use the wire:ignore directive to instruct Livewire to ignore
> the contents of a particular element, even if they change between
> requests.

Ref. https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/wire-ignore